# Calculating distance between 2 points. Can I trust in GeoLocation.STDistance function of sql server?

Tags: sql-server, geolocation, distance

I want to calculate the distance between two points with SQL server. The problem is that I get a result that is not accurate.

```
Create table #auxdist
(    idempr                 int identity(1,1)
,emp_desc               varchar(60) 
,longitud               float
,latitud                float
,geolocation            geography
)

insert into #auxdist values ('TIng',-55.769,-34.768,NULL)
insert into #auxdist values ('CComp',-55.74132,-34.19647,NULL)

Update  #auxdist
SET  [GeoLocation] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + cast( CAST(cs.latitud   AS decimal(30,20)) as varchar(30)) + ' ' + 
        cast( CAST(cs.longitud AS decimal(30,20)) as varchar(30))+ ')', 4326) 
 from  #auxdist cs 

select   com1.idempr,com2.idempr,           com1.GeoLocation.STDistance(com2.GeoLocation) as dist
 from    #auxdist com1
 join    #auxdist com2 on com1.idempr <> com2.idempr  and com1.idempr=1
```

Using this query I get that the distance between two points is 36016 mts.
Then I check the result using http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_greatcircle_distance.htm
and I found a different answer: 63673mts (Haversine formula)

[image: Distance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified your points backwards. Run the following query and you'll see what I mean.

```
select *, geolocation.Lat as Lat, geolocation.Long as Long
from #auxdist
```

The fix is easy enough: when you're creating the WKT via string concatenation, just switch the order of latitud and longitud

Comment: I forgot to mention that there's a much easier way to create your point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks to be your cast to decimal(30,20), is that really needed?  Plugging in the results below into the URL also gives much different result.

```
select 'POINT(' + cast( CAST(latitud AS decimal(30,20)) as varchar(30)) + ' ' + 
    cast( CAST(longitud AS decimal(30,20)) as varchar(30))+ ')'
from auxdist
```

Returns:

```
POINT(-34.76800000000000100000 -55.76899999999999800000)
POINT(-34.19646999999999800000 -55.74132000000000200000)
```

If you remove the cast to decimal, looks like you get proper coordinates:

```
select 'POINT(' + cast(latitud as varchar(30)) + ' ' + 
    cast(longitud as varchar(30))+ ')'
from auxdist
```

returns

```
POINT(-34.768 -55.769)
POINT(-34.1965 -55.7413)
```

Comment: Thanks @greg for your reply. The cast to decimal(30,20) is not needed. With your suggestion the query give a distance of 36014 mts.  The problem is that this number is not close to 63673 mts.